# How to link Tomcat server config in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, configuration, 19.04, tomcat, intellij

In **Java** class, my sir told me to link **Tomcat** server config which is inside Xampp folder. But his OS was Windows and things were different on my side since I use Ubuntu 19.04. I installed "**xampp-linux-x64-7.3.7-1-installer.run**" from their Official [website](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html).

But unfortunately, there is no such "**Tomcat**" folder like in my sir Windows OS.

So I installed Tomcat using "**sudo apt install tomcat9**" assuming its the latest stable built.

And I went to Intellij to add Tomcat's local server configuration, and showed the path "**/etc/tomcat9**" but the IDE says "**Application server libraries not found**" as u can see in the screenshot below:

[image: screenshot of an error]

***What to do? What am I missing? Help needed.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is putting:

- **/usr/share/tomcat9** in Tomcat_Home.
- **/var/lib/tomcat9** in Tomcat base directory.

As seen in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot]

*Note: Apparently, it is very important to add **Artifacts** in the 'Deployment' section and apply it.* Like this:
[image: Screenshot to where to go and add artifact]

Comment: I know the problem has been solved, but I just want to add something in case other people come across this forum. If you get an "Error running 'Tomcat 9.0.31 (Ubuntu)': Address localhost:8080 is already in use" just go to "Edit Configurations..." below "Tomcat Server Settings" change the HTTP port from 8080 to whatever port is free (8088 for example)